# Cannot Log In Bixby Studio

Tags: bixby, bixbystudio

Bixby Studio could not contact the authentication system at https://bixbydevelopers.com. Please check the URL url and your internet connection, and try again.

[error] [electron] Unable to fetch valid version from url: https://bixbydevelopers.com/dev/v2/valid-ide-version-range FetchError: request to https://bixbydevelopers.com/dev/v2/valid-ide-version-range failed, reason: unable to verify the first certificate
at ClientRequest. (C:\Users\hung.nv14\AppData\Local\Programs\BixbyStudio\resources\app.asar\node_modules\node-fetch\lib\index.js:1461:11)
at ClientRequest.emit (events.js:322:22)
at ClientRequest.EventEmitter.emit (domain.js:482:12)
at TLSSocket.socketErrorListener (_http_client.js:426:9)
at TLSSocket.emit (events.js:310:20)
at TLSSocket.EventEmitter.emit (domain.js:482:12)
at emitErrorNT (internal/streams/destroy.js:92:8)
at emitErrorAndCloseNT (internal/streams/destroy.js:60:3)
at processTicksAndRejections (internal/process/task_queues.js:84:21) {
type: 'system',
errno: 'UNABLE_TO_VERIFY_LEAF_SIGNATURE',
code: 'UNABLE_TO_VERIFY_LEAF_SIGNATURE'
}

Comment: Hello Hung, Can you please provide the Bixby Studio version as well?

Answer (score 0):

Is it possible that you are routing all of your network traffic through a proxy or VPN? If so, can you try without going through them?